# Finding points on an inverse function

Tags: functions, inverse

How do you verify if a point is on an inverse function of a graph if a point on the original function is given?

Comment: if i understand your question correctly the following should give you an answer: $\left(x,y\right)\in graph\left(f\right)\Leftrightarrow f\left(x\right)=y \Leftrightarrow x=f^{-1}\left(y\right)\Leftrightarrow \left(y,x\right)\in graph\left(f^{-1}\right)$

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks.